# wxWidgets and boost::thread?

Tags: networking, wxwidgets, boost-thread

I want to use boost to do background networking stuff in a loop while wxWidgets processes the GUI. I just started using wxWidgets so my first idea was to just start in the thread with networking loop inside OnInit of the app, but that wasn't a really good idea as the ap cannot continue running as the thread stops it.

How does one use boost::thread for multithreading and wxWidgets library together?

Comment: Have you considered using the wxWidgets wxThread class? There is also wxThreadEvent for messaging events back to the GUI.

Comment: @JohnPS I am looking for greater portability and boost::thread is really simpler to use. Another reason for this is because I already did the networking part beforehand as a console application.

Comment: You can start a seperate thread in OnInit if you wish, provided OnInit return true without blocking.  Are you doing this?  Why don't you post your code for OnInit()?

Comment: I think using a thread for networking in a GUI is not the best option, since at some point you'll have to synchronise with the GUI. Have you considered using boost::asio? I have used it with a wxTimer.

Answer (score 1):

you can start your networking part in OnInit() if you want but the listener needs to fork out to a different thread.having an io_service and at least one boost::thread that calls run on the io_service should do the trick.your network stuff will be carried on by the thread(s) calling io_service::run() and the master thread can return to doing wxWidgets stuff.